# How to turn on Bootstrap Intellisense in .NET 8 Blazor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, blazor

I might be mistaken but It looks like  .NET 8 Blazor does not support Bootstrap IntelliSense out of box. It's super annoying. Anyone knows any hacks to turn it on?

Thanks you!

I checked dependencies & verified CSS Paths.